# Localize MS Chart control

Tags: visual-studio, localization, mschart

Is it possible to localize MS Chart Control's print preview form? If so, then how?

.net4/c#/winforms/vs2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question. It seems that they did some custom dialog and forgot to localize it. I might be wrong but it appears that the only way would be to create your own dialog similar to .Net's and draw the chart on the CustomControl's surface using PrintPaint() method.
Sounds like a lot of work but it is actually fairly easy. The only problem I can think of is how to make sure that WYSIWYG :|